# Go's time doesn't work under the docker image from scratch

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var local,_ = time.LoadLocation("Asia/Shanghai")
    fmt.Println(time.Now())
    fmt.Println(time.Now().In(local))
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
COPY ./main /main
CMD [ "/main" ]
```

build.sh:

```
rm -rf main
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main  . 
docker build -t hello-go .
docker run hello-go
```

All the file are in one folder named hello-go. When I run my Go code in my osx. It works.

```html
➜  hello-go go run main.go
2017-12-13 21:50:53.482933 +0800 CST m=+0.000350077
2017-12-13 21:50:53.483007 +0800 CST
```

When i build the docker image and start it. one error like this:

```
➜  hello-go ./build.sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.937MB
Step 1/3 : FROM scratch
 --->
Step 2/3 : COPY ./main /main
 ---> 80da783f6c5d
Step 3/3 : CMD /main
 ---> Running in 85cb022b3ce2
 ---> 485ddd3a08dd
Removing intermediate container 85cb022b3ce2
Successfully built 485ddd3a08dd
Successfully tagged hello-go:latest
2017-12-13 13:52:59.861173734 +0000 UTC m=+0.000252335
panic: time: missing Location in call to Time.In

goroutine 1 [running]:
time.Time.In(0xbe846a0ef355744e, 0x4d607, 0x539b80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc420037f70)
        /usr/local/go/src/time/time.go:1073 +0xc0
main.main()
        /Users/liujichun/Desktop/workspace/docker/hello-go/main.go:11 +0xee
➜  hello-go
```

I know the scratch image is empty. What should i do to make it.

Comment: This post should point you in the right direction - https://www.goinggo.net/2013/08/using-time-timezones-and-location-in-go.html

Comment: Were do you expect the timezone information come from if you build your image from scratch?

Comment: From the image environment variable or write in the golang code.

Comment: I just want a minimum image to run go binary file. Empty is best.

Comment: You need to add the TZ data file.  If the app uses TLS, you will also need to include root certs.

Comment: OK, it's a good idea. Now I should find a way to reduce the TZ data file size.

Comment: You can include a subset of the zone info. Perhaps include  Asia/Shanghai and UTC only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this library https://godoc.org/4d63.com/tz

Their example (see `tz.LoadLocation`):

```
t := time.Date(2009, time.November, 10, 23, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
fmt.Println(t)

syd, _ := tz.LoadLocation("Australia/Sydney")
fmt.Println(t.In(syd))

// Output:

// 2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
// 2009-11-11 10:00:00 +1100 AEDT
```

Comment: This is no longer necessary (as of Go 1.15). You only need to import "time/tzdata" (prefix it with underscore) to get an embedded time zone database.

Answer (score 5):

I think the proper way to solve this is to import tzdata as the library wants it to be. You can make use of the `TZ` environment variable.

The solution is indicated in a Dockerfile which I found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Senorsen/docker-go-scratch/blob/master/Dockerfile)

To wrap up everything:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build
RUN apk update && apk add ca-certificates && apk add tzdata
WORKDIR /app
ADD . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o myapp

FROM scratch AS final
COPY --from=build /usr/share/zoneinfo /usr/share/zoneinfo
COPY --from=build /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=build /app/myapp /

ENV TZ Australia/Sydney
ENTRYPOINT ["/myapp"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Go 1.15, time/tzdata is available, just import the package in your main package.

Reference:
https://golang.org/pkg/time/tzdata/

Comment: This solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Docker FROM alphine

```
RUN apk --no-cache add tzdata
```

see answer in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62159987/4143613

Comment: Using alpine opens your container up to more attack vectors and is a heavy-handed approach. Using scratch is not only fine, but a good idea if you're going for security or performance. If you want access to platform-independent timezones, the above answer to use tz is honestly better.