# missing Location in call to Time.In

Tags: go, beego

When I ues beego/orm to operate postgresql database,there is an error like this "missing Location in call to Time.In".

code example

```
type dataTest struct {
    Id      int         `pk:"auto"`
    Data    time.Time   `orm:"auto_now;type(timestamp);null"`
}

local, _ := time.LoadLocation("UTC")
test_time, err := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02 15:04:05", "1111-01-25 14:27:07", local)
orm.DefaultTimeLoc = time.UTC

o,err := orm.NewOrmWithDB("postgres","default",db)
temp := new(dataTest)
temp.Id = 1
temp.Data = test_time
o.Update(temp)
```

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by `time.LoadLocation()` (in fact, don't ignore any errors). Also for UTC timezone use the `time.UTC` variable.

Answer (score 10):

For docker (build multi stage)

Install **tzdata** after build

```
RUN apk --no-cache add tzdata
```

List of time zones available, see: https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo_abbrs_windows.go

```
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Bogota")
now := time.Now().In(loc)
```

Comment: Life saviour spotted!

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

OS: Windows.

When I distribute the executable file to other computers, they encounter the following problem when running it.

> time: missing Location in call to Time.In

However, there are no issues when debugging the code on my own computer.

Later, I discovered that the problem was caused by the `time.LoadLocation` function, which references `runtime.GOROOT/lib/time/zoneinfo/zoneinfo.zip`<sup>[gorootZoneSource(runtime.GOROOT())](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/bcd82125f85c7c552493e863fa1bb14e6c444557/src/time/zoneinfo_read.go#L552-L562) [gorootZoneSource](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/bcd82125f85c7c552493e863fa1bb14e6c444557/src/time/zoneinfo_goroot.go#L13)</sup>. Therefore, if the `runtime.GOROOT` on other computers is different from that of the developer or even nonexistent, it will cause problems.

### Solution

Unzip `%GOROOT%/lib/time/zoneinfo/zoneinfo.zip`, select the desired time zone file, and use `embed` together with `time.LoadLocationFromTZData` to obtain the data for that region.

#### Example

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "time"
)

//go:embed zoneInfo
var zoneInfoFS embed.FS // get it from GOROOT/lib/time/zoneInfo.zip

func getLocation(name string) (loc *time.Location) {
    bs, err := zoneInfoFS.ReadFile("zoneInfo/" + name)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    loc, err = time.LoadLocationFromTZData(name, bs)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return loc
}

func main() {
    locTW := getLocation("Asia/Taipei")
    locJPN := getLocation("Asia/Tokyo")
}
```

Directory Structure

```
-main.go
- zoneInfo
  - Asia
      - Taipei
      - Tokyo
  - ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
type dataTest struct {
    Id      int         `pk:"auto"`
    Data    time.Time   `orm:"auto_now;type(timestamp);null"`
}

test_time, err := time.ParseInLocation("2006-01-02 15:04:05", "1111-01-25 14:27:07", time.UTC)
orm.DefaultTimeLoc = time.UTC

o,err := orm.NewOrmWithDB("postgres","default",db)
temp := new(dataTest)
temp.Id = 1
temp.Data = test_time
o.Update(temp)
```

Comment: I have the same problem but this did not work for me. Any other solutions?

Comment: I had the same issue, but I was running my application in Docker, with an alpine base image. What solved it for me was to install the tzdata OS package for alpine in the Dockerfile. (this GitHub repo helped me: https://github.com/takecy/tz-sample)

Answer (score 0):

Since Go 1.15 (released 2020-08-11) you can embed time zone info into your program. This allow not to rely on tzdata provided by OS.

`import _ "time/tzdata"`

See https://go.dev/doc/go1.15#time_tzdata